# Check if filesystem is case sensitive in node.js

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to find out if the filesystem for a certain directory is case-sensitive (like `ext4`) or case-**in**sensitive  (like `ntfs`) using Node.js?

Comment: Check that https://nodejs.org/fr/docs/guides/working-with-different-filesystems/

Comment: You could certainly design a quick test.  Create a temp file with a lowercase filename, then try do `fs.stat()` on it with a mix case version of the name and see if it's found.  Then, remove the temp file.